# with open in Python creates an empty file

Tags: python

this thing, is driving me crazy...

I use Python in order to write a file. 
And for testing purposes I limited it to a minimal:

```
with open(save_dir + filename + '.txt', 'w+') as out_file:
    out_file.write('HI\n')
```

This is a very simple thing. But the file is created to the correct directory, but nothing is written in it.

I'm asking for help to try and debug the code. Because of it's simplicity. I'm stuck.
What could possibly be the bug here? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a little more code context? For instance, something that would let us make sure `save_dir + filename` is giving the expected string?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: This is why this is crazy. I print the string before I enter the print, and it looks fine. 

I also mention that the file is created at the correct directory. But it's empty

Comment: If you delete the text file, before running the code again, will the empty file be created again (in the correct directory)?

Comment: @M.T yes. it is created in the correct directory but empty

Comment: @cardamom Python 2.7

Comment: Can you make it work without the `with` statement? ie. `out_file = open(...);out_file.write(...);out_file.close()`

Comment: @M.T. no. just tried that.

Comment: If you delete the directory and rerun, do you get a FileNotFound error at that point?

Comment: Also, what OS+platform are you on?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, because I make sure that the directory is created in previous parts of the code. And both the directory and the file are created without exceptions. The problem is that the output is not written. centOS 7

Comment: It works for me, your code exactly, just texted it. Are you trying to read it in python or opening it in the OS? If you are reading it in Python make sure you open it at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ok. I found something. I replaced `'save_dir + filename'` with `filename.txt` and it worked. The data where correctly written. But why the different scenario where the user specifed a directory doesnt work? where the file is created to the correct directory but nothing is written to it

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this when you run it outside the framework of "the rest of your code"

Comment: @MadPhysicist no, I can't

Comment: https://github.com/haypo/python-ptrace/blob/master/doc/syscall.rst

Comment: install that and then show us the system calls while running your script

Answer (score -2):

You have to import sys, if you want to use the filename variable.

```
from sys import argv
script,input_file,output_file = argv
content = open(input_file,"r").read()
t = open(output_file,"w")
t.write(content)
t.close()
```